# Return title of button being hovered on

Tags: javascript

I just want a bit of javascript to return the title of a button element that the user is hovering on.  I don't want to use `getElementById(...)` because I am making a function that works without referring to an element but it's ID.  Is this possible?

Many thanks :).

Comment: How do you expect to get the title from an Element, without using the Element?

Comment: When you say "title" do you mean `value`, and when you say "button" you mean `<button>...</button>`, right?

Comment: Why don't you attach 'mouseover' event to the buttons which will set some variable with it's title? Then you can use that variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `this` which refers to current element like this:

```
<input type="button" title="mytitle" onMouseOver='alert(this.title);'>
```

### [Working Example](http://jsbin.com/ulelot/3)

Answer (score 0):

**Js**

```
function showTitle(element){
  alert( element.getAttribute('title') );
}
```

**html**

```
<a href="#" title="I am the title" onmouseover="showTitle(this)">hover me</a>
```

***demo at*** http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/WKqMq/

Answer (score 0):

Consider this HTML:

```
<input type="button" value="Button 1" />
<input type="button" value="Button 2" />
<input type="button" value="Button 3" />
<input type="button" value="Button 4" />
<input type="button" value="Button 5" />

<div id="txt"></div>
```

And your JavaScript that will work on any button present in the current page

```
$("input[type=button]").bind("hover", function() {
    $("#txt").html($(this).val());
});
```

You may also consider looking at [LIVE Example](http://jsfiddle.net/ADuwr/)

Comment: I didn't see he said that anywhere! This is the cleanest code can be achieved such a requirement. Its obstructive - what better can you expect?

Answer (score 0):

You could also capture each button by using:

```
var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName("button");

for (var i=0; i < buttons.length; i++)
{ 
  buttons[i].onmouseover = function()
  {
    alert(this.title);
  }
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/2LP66/4/

This will alert the title of a button upon hovering off any button on the page.

The onmouseover function will only be run when you hover the button, but ofcourse you don't have to use an alert, you could also save the title in some more global scope and use this where you want to use the title